# how to change the label Fill pattern in c#

Tags: c#

Is there any way I can get the pattern of a label to change, ie. instead off just full red lets say i want the background colour to be red and it must have either vertical lines / horizontal lines etc)

Comment: Can you specify the Framework you are using? WinForms, WPF, QT, ...? This question is far to unspecific.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
Graphics g = lable1.CreateGraphics();
    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black,0,0,100,0);
```

Comment: you dont need to cast to control

Answer (score 2):

You can create your Label control inheriting from Label and override OnPaintBackground

```
class MyLabel: System.Windows.Forms.Label {

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs pevent) {
        HatchBrush brush = new HatchBrush(HatchStyle.Cross, Color.Red, Color.White);
        pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, ClientRectangle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it's like to "reinvent the wheel" IMHO

Comment: hard way to solve problem, when you can use standart functions